# Is there a slang meaning to "ダニ~ナｱｱ..."?

Tags: slang

"ダニ" said with a hard "ダ" and soft "ニ" is a bug.

But, isn't "ダニ" with a soft "ダ", hard "ニ", and trailing "ナｱｱｱ" a slang term? It means something like "he/she is a no good person who is inconsiderate of other's feelings", right?

> 長い間、待ち合わせていたが...
>   (私): "雅子さんに何度もすっぱかされて、連絡こなくって、ダニナｱｱｱ...."
>
> After waiting for a long time...
>   (me): "So many times I am being stood-up by Masako, she doesn't even tell me she is not coming. What a lowlife....

Anyway, I just heard someone talking about the "ダニ" bug, and I've got this feeling there is a slang term thats sounds like it.

Comment: Perhaps, isn't it 「だりぃ なぁ」? （→だるい）

Comment: My guess is the same, you probably have misheard だりい (slurred version of だるい which means "tiresome", "dull", etc). It's often considered as a typical 口癖 of young people. I'm posting this as a comment because, for now, this seems to be [a "simple spelling mistake" question](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1185/5010) which can be closed.